# Issues with PyCharm and printing example of data

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

So I'm trying to follow along to this [basic tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-tutorial-analyze-personal-netflix-data/). However, when I type df.head() PyCharm just says Process finished with exit code 0, and doesn't actually print anything.

So first question is why does

`df.head()`

print nothing but

`print(df.head()`

work?

The tutorial doesn't say anything about needing to use print().

Secondly, why does PyCharm keep breaking the table over multiple lines

[image]

There's clearly abundant space to the right of Duration for Title. But PyCharm insists on breaking a table over multiple lines. How do I get it to actually present in 5 rows instead of 10?

Comment: Also see [one of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+pd.options.display.max_columns&searchOn=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the following settings:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = <how many columns do you want to show?>
pd.options.display.width = <max width of the dataframe when printing>
```

Showing any output without using a print statement only works with the interactive console. if you run the file, it wont work. You can find the "Python console" in Pycharm in the bottom of the screen.

To execute your code in the console, you can either write it there or select the code and click the shortcut you can find (and set) under:
preferences -> keymap -> search for "execute selection in python console"

Comment: Thanks for that, that's resolve the second issue. Any idea why PyCharm needs print() to display anything, whereas Jupyter doesn't?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the question about print